# What is the Best Way to Monitor Server Temperature?

Tags: windows-server-2003, monitoring, physical-environment

I need to be able to monitor the temperature of a couple of servers remotely.  Does anyone know of any free/cheap software that will monitor the server temp and email it or at least output it so that I can pick it up via blat?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you were running Linux

For CPU and board:
lm_sensors + NetMRG or Nagios

For disks:
hddtemp or smartctl (smartmontools) + NetMRG or Nagios

Since you are running Windows, speedfan may be of some use.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, server hardware will have temperature sensors pollable via IPMI. This is true back to all the servers I have, even generic brands, to about 2002... and is also true for my home PC.

On linux, you can access this information using the `ipmitool`. Some servers also expose it to `snmp` if you have the appropriate MIB for your vendor. Servers without an ipmi interface may expose the data through `lm_sensors`.

On windows, you can use the [ipmiutil](http://ipmiutil.sourceforge.net/home.htm) project to access ipmi information... there are a variety of other ways to do it, and I'm not a windows admin so I can't tell you for sure what the best way is, but you might consider running the windows version of NRPE to provide secure access to the data for nagios.

Comment: You may have missed that the question is tagged with [windowsserver2003].

Comment: Oops. Sure did. Thanks, I've edited my response appropriately.

Comment: NO!!!  I edited it AFTER you asked!  Since I don't deal with Linux, I rarely think about other's using it when they read my questions.  My bad.

Comment: IPMI is OS-independent, you just need to get the right client for it. It could even be on a remote, networked machine running a completely different operating system.

Answer (score 2):

Nagios and Zenoss are both extensible enough that you should be able to implement temperature monitoring easily, and they're both free.

If you want to be really simple just write a script that uses the lm_sensors tools and emails the answer, then schedule it with cron. Really, that's only a good course of action if you have just a couple of servers, but it is quick and easy to manage.

Depending on your servers there may be tools with them, or you can use SNMP too. I know the Dell PowerEdge's come with the web based servertools to alert on this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Munin with this [plugin](http://muninexchange.projects.linpro.no/?search=&cid=0&os[5]=on&os[6]=on&pid=323). Works great.