# Lightweight temperature monitoring on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, monitoring, dell, physical-environment

I'm working for a small organization, and I'm currently looking for a quick and easy way to monitor server temperature (Possibly graphing it, though having an emailed warning would be o.k.)

I'm currently using Dell's OpenManage tool, which doesn't really cut it in terms of logging.

Comment: Do you want to monitor the server from the server itself, or from another machine?

Comment: I'm looking to monitor the server from itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm a big fan of PRTG Network Monitor from www.paessler.com.  Its a packaged Windows version of MRTG (or at least inspired by it), and does all sorts of useful data collection, graphing, notification, etc.  Its inexpensive and has saved my butt.

I also use an environmental monitor from IT Watchdogs.  I think I paid $400 bucks for it, and I have at least one in every server room I manage.  I knew fairly quickly when the AC went out in my remote office and was able to alert them to take action.

Answer (score 1):

Motherboard Monitor is a long time fave of mine.

http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Info/Motherboard-Monitor.shtml

Comment: Motherboard Monitor isn't maintained anymore though (practically stopped in 2004 though I think there was one minor update in 2006).

Answer (score 1):

You might look into [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/).  I haven't played with the version that runs on windows but it was very easy to set up on linux and is successfully monitoring many SNMP sources in our data center.  Environmental monitors, Cisco Switches, and a couple Dell 2950s.

Comment: Cacti is an organization-wide SNMP monitoring tool; this is is sort of akin to recommending a laser-guided wrench-wielding robot when what the person really needs is a crescent wrench, no?

Comment: Well sure, but on the other hand it will do what is wanted for very little setup time and very little cost. Nobody says you have to use all of it just because it's there.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of points to monitor on the server (processor and cores, board, disks, chassis). Typical server machines come with quite a few sensors and there are good tools to track them. There is another thread discussing the [Best Way to Monitor Server Temperatures](https://serverfault.com/questions/22544/what-is-the-best-way-to-monitor-server-temperature) and this has quite a few references and suggestions that may be valuable for you.